# how to implement positionindicator for bezel (Galaxy watch 4 Classic) wear os 3.0 (jetpack compose)?

Tags: wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4, compose-wear

They know how to implement the scroll by bezel (Galaxy watch 4 Classic) in wear os 3.0 with jetpack compose

In the documentation it mentions the use of ScalingLazyListState or ScrollState but so far the scroll with the rotating bezel of my device has not been recognized.

if anyone has information or an example it would help me a lot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a wear-compose slack channel that can help also - https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up

Comment: I was about to provide a sample, but want to confirm it is correct first. It may be out of date https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace/pull/84/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wear Compose Alpha 15, it is now supported.

```
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    ScalingLazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onRotaryScrollEvent {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    scrollState.scrollBy(it.verticalScrollPixels)
                }
                true
            }
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable(),
        state = scrollState,
```

and then either when the screen is shown, or possible driven by paging (if using HorizontalPager) call requestFocus()

```
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
```

Comment: Excellent!!
it was what you need, thank you very much.

Comment: This is now supported in Wear Compose 1.0.0-alpha15, but it also breaks this workaround.

Comment: not working in my case!

Comment: It's used extensively in the samples for Horologist https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/75c898a562c9fee37877d8710330a8b7751c7264/compose-layout/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/compose/navscaffold/ScrollableColumn.kt

So it definitely works.  Maybe try the sample apps there and see if it works for you, or it's your device?