# Samsung Galaxy 4 classic bezel rotation detection in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I want to be able to add a value to an integral that I have:

Rotating clockwise would increase the value by one

Rotating counter-clockwise would decrease the value by one

I tried searching and I found "rotary input", but I didn't really manage to put it in practice (I mostly found it all talking about scrollview)

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

For Compose you can use the onRotaryInputAccumulated modifier from Horologist

Example for volume control

https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/94552e13ea45613cc9b804ee7080b4aa92311d54/audio-ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/audio/ui/VolumeScreen.kt#L108-L114

The raw events come from onRotaryScrollEvent [how to implement positionindicator for bezel (Galaxy watch 4 Classic) wear os 3.0 (jetpack compose)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060650/how-to-implement-positionindicator-for-bezel-galaxy-watch-4-classic-wear-os-3/70062947#70062947)

For Views use https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/rotary-input